Restoring Active Directory user object
I'm trying to restore a AD user object via Powershell.
I was able to lookup the deleted object using the following powershell command:
get-adobject -filter 'Name -like "<name-of-deleted-user>*" -AND IsDeleted -eq $True' -IncludeDeletedObjects

When i try restore the object with the Restore-ADObject command, i get the following error: The server is unwilling to process the request.
I tried to restore using both the GUID, DN and by adding the | Restore-ADObject to the first command. All gives the same result.
Any ideas what goes wrong? And should i just prepare to recreate the user manually when seeing the error?
Above is done from an elevated Powershell.

Was the AD Recycle Bin feature enabled in the forest when the user object was deleted?

That's a really good point. I assumed it was, as the object lookup was successful.
But i have checked, and it seems not enabled. To bad for me.
Thanks for the quick reply

Well, you don't need a recycle bin to delete objects :)

Try restoring it with the AD RID Role owner, can sometimes be an issue if your AD structure has multiple domains within the forest.
If the AD OU the user was in have been changed/deleted, you might also have to specify the "-TargetPath" OU for the user.
$Name = "Tim"
$DeletedObject = Get-Adobject -includedeletedobject -filter * | where {$_.isdeleted -eq $true -and $_.name -like $Name}
$DeletedObject | Restore-ADObject -Server (Get-ADDomain).RIDMaster -whatif

